# Resize flash.media.Video

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video

I'm having trouble to resize my custom `UIComponent` that wrap `flash.media.Video` object (The reason I choose this way is because `mx.control.VideoDisplay` doesn't support streaming playback that available in `flash.media.Video` that is `attachNetStream()`). Once I create a 320x240 `Video` size and remove it from its parent, I can't replace it with another one, bigger or smaller.

Here's my code (this one only capture Camera not NetStream).

```
package media
{
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    import mx.controls.VideoDisplay;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class VideoUI extends UIComponent
    {
        private var video:Video;

        public function VideoUI(width:int, height:int)
        {
            super();
            video = new Video(width, height);
            var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            video.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(video);
        }
    }
}
```

The other part,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import media.VideoUI;

            private function addVideoOutput():void
            {
                // initial video size
                var video:VideoUI = new VideoUI(160,120);
                HBoxVideo.addChild(video);              
            }

            protected function resizeVideo(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var videoList:Array = HBoxVideo.getChildren();
                for (var i:int = 0; i < videoList.length; i++)
                {
                    var video:VideoUI = videoList.pop();
                    HBoxVideo.removeChild(video);
                    // new size that produce the previous size :(
                    video = new VideoUI(320, 240);
                    HBoxVideo.addChild(video);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button click="addVideoOutput()" x="10" y="265" label="add"/>
    <mx:HBox x="10" y="10" width="100%" id="HBoxVideo">
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:Button x="58" y="265" label="resize" click="resizeVideo(event)" id="resizeButton"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, new instances of the Video class are 320 pixels wide by 240 pixels high. You will need access to your *video* in the *VideoUI* Class so that you can change the *width* and *height*.

As follows:

Change all appearances of your *video* variable in VideoUI.as to

```
_video
```

and apply a getter.

**New Video UI Class**

```
package media
{
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class VideoUI extends UIComponent
    {
        private var _video:Video;

        public function VideoUI(width:int, height:int)
        {
            super();
            _video = new Video(width, height);
            var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            _video.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(_video);
        }

        public function get video():Video{
            return _video;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace in **your main mxml file**

```
video = new VideoUI(320, 240);
```

with

```
video.video.width=320;
video.video.height=240;
```

Note: You should rename your *VideoUI* instance to *videoui* or the sorts. It is a little confusing. You can also move this to your VideoUI Class or make a method. The choice is yours.

Comment: You're right, I should have access Video's property instead VideoUI.
My bad.